# How can I create a hyperlink on image in a Tableau tooltip?

Tags: hyperlink, tooltip, tableau-api

does anyone know how to set a hyperlink to an image shown in a tooltip in Tableau? Or even better: show the thumbnail of a website and be able to click it to get to the website. I managed to insert an image with the custom shapes function. Any help is appreciated!